# Removing the file part of the output from du in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to remove the output when calling `du` in my bash script. I'm just trying to print out the size of the current directory. So it looks like this:

```
DIRSIZE=$(du -hs $1)
printf "The size of the directory given is: %s\n" "$DIRSIZE"
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
The size of the directory given is: 32K
```

However, my command currently outputs:

```
The size of the directory given is: 32K /home/dir_listed/
```

Is there an easy way to remove the directory?

Comment: pipe into `awk 'NF--'`

Comment: Or `du -hs "$1" | awk '{ print "The size of the directory given is: " $1 }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **awk**:

```
DIRSIZE=$(du -hs $1 | awk '{print $1}')
```

Take only the first field from `du` output and save to `DIRSIZE`.

With **sed**:

```
DIRSIZE=$(du -hs $1 | sed 's/[[:space:]].*//')
```

Remove from first `space` to end of line and save to `DIRSIZE`.

With **cut**:

```
DIRSIZE=$(du -hs $1 | cut -f 1)
```

Take only the first field from `du` output which is tab seperated and save to `DIRSIZE`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DIRSIZE=$(du -hs $1 | awk '{print $1}')
printf "The size of the directory given is: %s\n" "$DIRSIZE"
```